# QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running - invoked by QPushbutton

Tags: c++, qt

I was for hours trying to reduce this error to a minimal example, but could not succeed.

I have a GUI with a `QPushButton importPCDButton`. It should open a `QFileDialog` and import the selected file.  I want to use a thread hoping that the dialog vanishes as soon as I send an update signal to my GUI.  So I have an `ImportPCD` worker class derived from `QObject` implementing a public slot with the name `process()`.  Inside this, I open the `QFileDialog`, etc:

```
 void ImportPCD::process() {
     std::cout << "foo \n";
     QString file_abs = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
         &*(getControl()->getGuiPtr()),
         tr("OpenFile"),
         "../data/",
         tr("Point Cloud File(*pcd);;ASCII - File(*.asc);;All Files(*)"));
     int index = file_abs.lastIndexOf("/");
     int size = file_abs.size();
     int position = size-index-1;    
     QString file = file_abs.right(position);
     index = file.indexOf(".");
     file = file.left(index);
     getControl()->setTreeID(file.toStdString());
     QString abort;
     if(file!=abort)
     {
         this->path = file_abs.toStdString();

         cloudRGB = import ();
         emit updateUI();
         computeNormals (cloudRGB);
         emit updateUI();
         principalCurvatures = computeCurvature ();

         setRGB ();
         getControl()->setCloudPtr(getCloudRGB());
    }

    emit finished();
}
```

It also implements the slots `updateUI()` and `finished()`.

I have a public slot `importPCDFile()` in my GUI:

```
void PCLViewer::importPCDFile() {
    boost::shared_ptr<QThread> thread_ptr (new QThread);
    boost::shared_ptr<ImportPCD> importWorker (new ImportPCD(control));
    importWorker->moveToThread(&*thread_ptr);
//  connect (ui->importPCDButton  , SIGNAL(clicked()), &*thread_ptr, SLOT(start()));
    connect (&*thread_ptr, SIGNAL(started()), &*importWorker, SLOT(process()));
//  connect (ui->importPCDButton  , SIGNAL(clicked()), &*importWorker, SLOT(process()));
    connect (&*importWorker, SIGNAL(updateUI()), this, SLOT(updateUI()));
    connect (&*importWorker, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(updateUI()));
    connect (&*importWorker, SIGNAL(finished()),&*thread_ptr, SLOT(quit()));
//  connect (&*importWorker, SIGNAL(finished()),&*thread_ptr, SLOT(quit()));
    connect (&*thread_ptr, SIGNAL(finished()), &*thread_ptr, SLOT(deleteLater()));
//  connect (&*thread_ptr, SIGNAL(finished()), &*importWorker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    thread_ptr->start();

}
```

This method is invoked when I press the button and I get the error:

`QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running`

Comment: You are probably creating a race condition by calling slots like that, I don't think it's safe. You could try to use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` on inter thread boundaries.

Comment: p.s. The `thread_ptr is` destroyed on end of scope. You need it either as member or use other ways of lifetime managing.

Comment: Declared thread_ptr as  a  member variable now, resulting in other errors. Found another solution now.

Comment: Don't do GUI stuff outside of the main thread. You should open the file dialog in the main thread.